# What is the recommended read/write speed for an SSD when syncing an archive node?

Tags: synchronization, hardware

I am planning to sync an archive node for research purposes and am preparing to buy the hardware. How does the read/write speed of the SSD affect the sync speed? Is 500 MB/S enough, or would an upgrade to a faster, more expensive SSD improve the sync speed?

And more generally: Where is usually the bottleneck for sync speed?

And on a related note, does it matter if the storage space is split accross multiple SSDs? Can geth/partiy handle this automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question.. pitty that no one has answered.  In my case, something that works (might be over-the-top) is "Crucial BX500" SATA III SSD with read 540 MB/s and write 500 MB/s.

Answer (score 3):

In our experience at Moralis where we've been syncing A LOT of full archive nodes both on Ethereum and BSC, the read/write speed of the disk is actually not as important as you might think.

On most nodes, the average speed ranges from 70 to 300 MB/s read/write when the node is synchronizing. Generally, you cannot achieve a higher speed, since the bottleneck is CPU, and the sync process is not multithreaded. Even running in RAID0 doesn't impact the synchronisation time.

The real bottlenecks in terms of synching a full archive node is the number of reliable peers and processing time per block.

The only real way of speeding up sync time is to copy the chaindata from another trusted node. But unless it's 100% trusted, you would be comprimising security.

I hope that helps.